# CheckStyle rule or similar to prevent == on nonprimitive datatypes?

Tags: java, checkstyle, findbugs

In a bigger project I'm working in there seem to be several occurences of == comparisons on Integers which lead to 'wrong' behaviour. I'd like to refactor that but CheckStyle which is currently used in the project only offers StringLiteralEqualityCheck (which only checks for == on Strings) and doing a regular search for == finds way to much occurences for a manual check.

Has anybody a tool or an open source rule for CS to address this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean a tool that goes through your code and checks whether you are using == on Objects? Try Sonar(Cube).

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This is not off-topic. Static code analysis questions are traditionally discussed on SO (see tag history).

Comment: This is off-topic sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkstyle is not really helpful in this case, but [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net) (or better, its successor [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/)) can probably help.

Examples for such checks are:

- [Suspicious reference comparison to constant](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RC_REF_COMPARISON_BAD_PRACTICE) ([SpotBugs version](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bugDescriptions.html#rc-suspicious-reference-comparison-to-constant-rc-ref-comparison-bad-practice))
- [Suspicious reference comparison](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RC_REF_COMPARISON) ([SpotBugs version](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bugDescriptions.html#rc-suspicious-reference-comparison-rc-ref-comparison))
- [Suspicious reference comparison of Boolean values](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RC_REF_COMPARISON_BAD_PRACTICE_BOOLEAN) ([SpotBugs version](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bugDescriptions.html#rc-suspicious-reference-comparison-of-boolean-values-rc-ref-comparison-bad-practice-boolean))

Comment: Thank you a lot, precise and helpful!

Answer (score 1):

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/ is the easiest way to tackle such situations.

It will throws errors something like - suspicious comparison of Integer references